# SSRS report - Casing parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm having an issue with an SSRS report in Report builder 3. I'm attempting to use a parameter which is being cased to show text instead of the int datatype of the field. Report Builder spits out an error every time i try to preview the report. I've tried casting and converting the data type, but still get the same error. Any insight would be much appreciated. Below is the query that the parameter is sourcing and the error message.

--Query

```
select distinct case convert(varchar(10),workorderstatusid)
when '1' then 'Open'
when '2' then 'Closed'
when '105' then 'OnHold'
when '101' then 'Cancelled'
end  as 'Status'
from tasks
```

--Error message

```
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
----------------------------
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
```

-- Dataset 1 - main query

```
select wo_num as 'Word Order ID',isnull(dept,'Unassigned') as 'Department', 
task as 'Summary', isnull(descript, 'No Description') as 'Notes', 
respons as 'Assigned Technician', duedate as 'Due Date',completed as 'Date Completed',
isnull(status,'Incomplete') as 'Status'
from tasks
where (workorderstatusid =@status)
and (dept=@department)
order by wo_num asc
```

Comment: This error occurs when `dataset` is comes empty that is no data is fetched from the database. Try testing your connection and query if they working correctly

Comment: The dataset works just fine and so do the queries, ive tested using the parameter without the case, so the drop down displays the numbers instead of the text and it parses data just fine. The issue lies with the casing. I dont understand why. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: What have you tried for the parameter casing can you add it in the question

Comment: i dont really understand the question, but i've added the main query above. The parameter is sourcing another dataset which is the one i've having the problem with. If i remove the case statement and simply do a distinct query for the parameter, it works just fine, but the the drop down for the parameter gives me numbers, which is what i'm trying to avoid with the case statement.

Comment: In your main `datset` query you are matching the `workorderstatusid =@status` but inthis @status comes as string where as `workorderstatusid` is numeric type so this may be causing the problem

Comment: check if your main dataset query is able to fetch data using the any hardcoded string value in place of status

Comment: exactly, how can i get the multivalue parameter to show the strings in the case from an int data type field like **workoderstatusid**

Comment: yes it can, i have a second parameter in the report which is **@department** that sources the **dept** field of varchar data type and that works just fine.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want? do you want to display int values in string format on the report ?

Comment: i want the drop down for the parameter to display the strings `open, closed, onhold, cancelled` as i cased them in the query above instead of the actual values from the field which are `1,2,105,101`

Comment: So what is type of the parameter that is attached to the dropdown check its datatype and set it as `Text`

Comment: currently it is set to text and thats the error i get, when i change it to int another error comes up saying it cannot convert the data type

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out guys, needed to include this statement prior to the main query

```
if (@status = 'Open')
begin 
      set @status = 1
end
else if (@status = 'Closed')
Begin
      set @status = 2
End
else if (@status = 'OnHold')
Begin
      set @status = 105
End
else if (@status = 'Cancelled')
Begin
      set @status = 101
End
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the parameter and set it's Type as Text and multiple values checked as below

[image]

And then set the default values to set by query and select the dataset

[image]